# How to point GoDaddy subdomain to Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I have checked all existing Questions & Answers relating to this but it is very confusing to implement old answers with the updated ui of GoDaddy DNS.

What I have done so far is added domains to my app by using command: 
`heroku domains:add xyz.com --app xyz`.

But I am not sure what exactly I need to enter while creating CNAME record. I have tried create different CNAME record according to different answers but none worked.

Is there a book about DNS or similar that I can read to understand such issue and fix it? I have called GoDaddy but the support guy didn't care much to help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To connect your heroku hosting to godaddy,

You have to open your godaddy account and in the DNS Management page add in the **cname** the host: `www` and in the point to: `your heroku url`
And in the heroku page in the settings add three domains:

```
1 *.xyz.com 
2: xyz.com
3. www.xyz.com
```

This should work :) Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You are welcome :) I made the youtube video for you. Please like and subscribe ;)

Comment: how to do it with subdomain but not the root one? example: www.app.xyz.com